# Adjust Bundle JRE for MAC inInstall4j

Tags: java, javafx, install4j

I'm using Install4j to create a installer of a JavaFx application for OSX and it must include a bundle JRE (`jre 1.7_0_51`).
I need to move the file `/lib/jfxrt.jar` to `/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar` to force Java to load the JavaFX libs.

Is there a way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

I've forget to add a little info about the bundle, the file jfxrt.jar is inside the bundle.

Comment: Just to move the file from one folder to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In install4j, you can use a "Move files and directories" action to move a file.

Comment: Please, check my update in the question. Sorry for not post it before.

Answer (score 0):

run this:

```
$: mkdir /lib/ext
$: mv /lib/jfxrt.jar /lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
```